# search with # % _ + in mysql query LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code ( just some part of it) :

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['act']) && $_GET['act']== 'do')  {
$key= $_POST['key'];
}
else {
$key= '';
}
?>

<input class='inputField' type='text' name='key' size=45 value='<?php echo $key;?>' > 

<script>$(document).ready(function(){
key= $("#mainTop input").val();
if(key!= null || key== '%') {
    showPage(1,key);
}
else    {
    showPage(1);
}
});
</script>
```

The showpage() will get parameter and pass to php file :

```
if(isset($_GET['key'])) {
$key= addslashes($_GET['key']);
}
else {
$key= null;
}
$result= $db->query("SELECT * FROM information WHERE stuId LIKE '%$key%' OR stuName LIKE '%$key%' LIMIT  $start,10");
```

The php file will get the key to search. I escape the key by addslashes,the do the mysql query to search.
But if I search with key = % # _ +,it still print our all the table instead there are no matching result.
I guess that I did not escape the key in right way,so how do I escape character such as % # _ + to do  mysql query with LIKE ?
Please help me out ? I had a look at some another question but I still dont get it

Comment: Why are you adding slashes? + if it's user input, then you should really be using prepared statements

Comment: Why do you want to search with `% # _ +` ?

Comment: It's not necessary to use prepared statements at all.

Comment: @popnoodles it's user input, so to prevent possible problems from a user modifing the params on the URL, use prepared statements or proper escaping to avoid problems

Comment: It's one way of doing it, yes.

Comment: Tks guy.Can prepared statements fix all the escape character problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, `#` and `+` are not special characters in a LIKE match string, but you simply need to [escape the others](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

```
$key = str_replace(array('%', '_'), array('\%', '\_'), $key);
```

Comment: But I used addslahsed so it supposed to be \% or \ _ when I do the query ,but while the query still do not as I expected ?

Comment: @DucAnh It's probably best in your case to not use addslash, rather manipulate the $_GET data by using this sort of example

Comment: @DucAnh [`addslashes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) only escapes apostrophe, quote, backslash, and the null byte -- not percent or underscore.

Comment: @Pills Tks,I got it. But what about # and +,as I know # define comment in mysql.So how to escape them? I try to add them in your given answer but it doesnt work ?

Comment: @DucAnh `#` is only a comment outside of a string literal.  As long as it's inside of a string, it has no special meaning.  I don't think that `+` is ever special outside of regexen.

Comment: But if I search with abc#d,it will search for only abc cause #d is the comment part in mysql.What have I do to search with abc#d

Comment: @DucAnh no, you're wrong.  Try `SELECT ... WHERE stuId = 'abc#d'

Comment: I tried as you say in phpmyadmin and you are right.But while my code still print out all the table if I have any # in the key string ?
The process is : input->submit->print Get sumbit in input field -> .val() input field -> pass to jQuery function -> pass to PHP file 
Which part of the process where the problem started,and how to fix it ?

Comment: What is the value of `$key`?  Are you sure it's not an empty string?

Comment: I use Ajax GET to pass to PHP file and check the $_GET['key'] as in my code

Answer (score 1):

A solution to this problem is simply to use parameterized queries.

You wont have to worry about escaping.
You protect yourself from SQL injection.
Your code will be taken more seriously by your peers and people looking to hire you.

Keep in mind that you are dealing with three levels that need to be escaped. E.G. in PHP you must escape `'` unless you want it to be interpreted as a quote, the mysql query itself must escape the same `'`, manually (`\'`) with something like addslashes or using prepared statements, and the regular expression within the mysql query must be escaped if it is a reserved character like `%` or `_` are in a `LIKE` statement.

Comment: DO you mean prepared statement in mysqli ?

Comment: Prepared statements are a way to implement parameterized queries and [mysqli prepared statements](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#MySQLi_Prepared_Statements_Wrapper) will certainly solve your problems. Here is a [parameterized query cheatsheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet) for any other languages you know. Most people prefer [PDO](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#PDO_Prepared_Statement_Wrapper) for php. Personally, I use a framework with it's own method for building parameterized queries.

Comment: Tks for your suggestion :)

Comment: I just change my code with prepared statement,but the problem with # % _ + still remain.Do you know how to escape # + in the query ?

Comment: Escape any single character by appending `\ ` to the front like `\%`. `addslashes($var)` will escape everything, `$mysqli->real_escape_string($var);` if using mysqli. If you're just looking to escape % and _ look at Explosion Pills' answer. Keep in mind that you are dealing with three levels that need to be escaped. E.G. in PHP you must escape `'` unless you want it to be interpreted as a quote, the mysql query itself must escape the same `'`, manually (`\'`) or using prepared statements, and the regular expression within the mysql query must be escaped if it is a reserved character, like `%`.

Comment: But with plushsign character '+' I cant escape it with \ or real_escape_string.How to search a string with '+',it always change to space in sql query and I dont know how to fix that.Btw,# is also a problem :(